# Can we call Stored procedure as webhook(just fire and terminate)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-mvc, simplejdbccall

I am using JAVA as my backend code and SQL server as my database server and  i am calling a Stored procedure and it's very huge sp so i am breaking it  into 3 sp's and calling it. but i just want to trigger one sp and it should continue it's task and only i should do is to check in every 1 min or so  but i when i am calling the sp my java is waiting till the sp returns the value.

if i use webhook i can achieve this but i just want to use through stored procedure.

SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(Master.getJdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("sp_getDetails");
        jdbcCall.setProcedureName("sp_getDetails");

Map m = jdbcCall.execute();

Comment: Have a look at java.util.concurrent.Future - essentially farm the call out to a background thread and choose when you want to look for the result.

Comment: @Richard Why don't you provide an example as an answer?

Comment: @Richard but i don't want any result i just want to fire a stored procedure and continue my other java work.i mean to say, the particular thread must  suspend after calling that stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to make use of `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`

```
ExecutorService executor = ...;
FutureTask<Map> future = new FutureTask<Map>(new Callable<Map>() {
    public Map call() {
        return jdbcCall.execute();
    }});
executor.execute(future);
```

You can then just ignore looking for the result of the `future` object - but the `executor` will run your call in a background thread and then just end. Meanwhile, the current thread (ie that makes the `executor.execute` call) will just carry on executing without blocking.